# How to update java class dynamically at runtime (like hot deployment)

Tags: classloader, hotdeploy

I'd like to update java classes dynamically at runtime (just like hot deployment) . Is there solution for that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way to update a class that has already been loaded by the JVM is bytecode instrumentation. Java instrumentation agents can use methods `redefineClasses` and `retransformClasses` of the [java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) class. Native agents can use respective functions `RedefineClasses` and `RetransformClasses` of the [JVMTI API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.htm).